# Angular 2 (final, not beta) unit tests (inject, TestBed) - How do I spy on function called in service constructor (service unit test)?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testbed

I injected the service in TestBed, which means the constructor method is called outside my control. So where/how do I set up a spy?

```
describe('MySvc', () => {

     beforeEach(() => {        
         TestBed.configureTestingModule({
             providers: [
                 MySvc,
                 spyOn(MySvc, "methodcalledinconstructor")
             ]
         });
     });


     it("should test all aspects of the service",
         inject([MySvc], fakeAsync((mySvc) => {

             expect(mySvc.methodcalledinconstructor).toHaveBeenCalled();
             // the above check fails! Help me here.

         }));    
     });
 });
```

Comment: What kind of service would require a method call in constructor? if the method is here for initialization (populate field), you should check the field where you store the inialized datas and expect is not to be null/undefined.

Comment: This is a logging service. The constructor method creates the logger and calls some methods that complete the logger's functionality so it is ready to use.

Comment: I do have other ways to check what the service does, or that that method is called (by checking for other changes). I just wish I could check the method has been called directly.

Comment: the problem is not the spy, it's the fact that the object is created by the constructor and you don't exactly know when. In order to add the spy before the constructor is created, you should call spyOn before you call TestBed.configureTestingModule

Comment: You should just test the state of the service; that all the initialization is done correctly. Trying to spy on the method is pointless. Spying is used for when you want to check the a method was called by a _consumer_ of the service. There should be no need to spy on the service you are testing. Whatever methods you wanted to spy on, should alter some state of the service. And that's what you want to test